sPLS-DA variance and loading
I'm using mixOmics::splsda in R to make prediction. X is a numerical matrix of 400x70 for the concentration of 70 proteins in 400 samples. Y is a binary label of the samples. I firstly tried the following:
re1=mixOmics::splsda(X,Y,ncomp = 70)

Some results:

re1$prop_expl_var$Y[1] is 1, and min(re1$prop_expl_var$Y) is 0.86. prop_expl_var is the Proportion of variance explained per component after setting possible missing values in the data to zero
range(re1$prop_expl_var$X) is 0.004 to 0.14
re1$prop_expl_var$X[1] is 0.019, and range(re1$loadings$X) is -0.32 to 0.34

Can the following statements be made?

X contains all the information in Y because the 1st PC already contains all the variance in Y.
Variation in Y is a reflection of the variation of all 70, instead of a few, of the proteins because

the minimum proportion of variance in Y explained by any of the 70 PCs is 0.86, still very large.
the coefficients between any protein and any PC are between -0.3 and 0.3; that is, no PC is dominated by only a few proteins.


Large majority of information in proteins are not related to Y because the proportions of variance in protein explained by each PC is small, ranging from 0.004 to 0.14

Cross validation suggests only the 1st PC and two proteins should be used in building the model. But at the end the prediction accuracy is poor. Could anyone explain possible reasons for the poor performance?
Thanks!
